# Which would be the undefined article in singular for Ag0/AgCl reference electrodes?

Tags: nomenclature

The Google exact match searches for ["an Ag0/AgCl reference electrode"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22an%20Ag0%2FAgCl%20reference%20electrode%22&client=ubuntu&hs=9uf&ei=GzVwYpaJCYWsqtsP97yluAc&ved=0ahUKEwjWgtayysH3AhUFlmoFHXdeCXcQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22an%20Ag0%2FAgCl%20reference%20electrode%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQtg5Ytg5g5hRoAXAAeACAAbQDiAG0A5IBAzQtMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) and ["a Ag0/AgCl reference electrode"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20Ag0%2FAgCl%20reference%20electrode%22&client=ubuntu&hs=1Z0&ei=ADVwYtueBrzcqtsP1r6bmAw&ved=0ahUKEwjbnuOlysH3AhU8rmoFHVbfBsMQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22a%20Ag0%2FAgCl%20reference%20electrode%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjoHCAAQRxCwA0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFCjF1jsJWC8KGgCcAF4AIABkgWIAbELkgEJMi0yLjEuMC4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) yields the same few results. Which usage would be more appropriate, for example, in the next sentence?

> Electric potential differences were measured using a lead ion-selective electrode and a/an Ag0/AgCl reference electrode.

Would it be more consistent to say *a silver/silver chloride reference electrode*?

Comment: I'd use "a" because I would pronounce "Ag" as "silver".

Comment: It all depends how one would read Ag/AgCl. If you have silver in mind then spell it out, if you have Ag in mind then "an" should go with it. Google scholar shows about 98,000 results with "an Ag/AgCl", and about 62000 with "a Ag/AgCl".